# Jquery Photostack plugin problems with IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using Photostack, https://code.google.com/p/jquery-photostack/downloads/list 
a Jquery plugin gallery on a website :

http://twin-focus-photography.co.uk/recentviewer.php?&albumid=d5906ce4e2

The problem I am having is for some reason IE really doesnt like it and its not showing up, it works fine in Chrome.

So im not sure if its my code or what is going on with it ?.

```
          <script src="js/photostack/photostack.js"></script>

          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('div.images').photostack({
                    'speed':400,
                    'float':'left',
                    'overlay':'false'
                });
            });
        </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").css("display", "none");

        $("body").fadeIn(2000);

        $(".recentviewerclose").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("body").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);      
        });

        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: which IE-Version are we talking bout?

Comment: ie 10, but it does it in 9,8 compatibility too.